# If we have % share of something, does it make sense to take mean of the absolute nos. and the std deviation of the share values instead

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation

I have a dataset with two columns; one is the total time played by a player on a gaming console and the other is the time played online which will always be less than or equal to the total time played by the player. The data looks like the following

[image]

I was asked to take the mean by dividing the sum of online playtime hours by the sum of total playtime hours whereas to take the std deviation by using the online playtime share. My concern is shouldn't there be consistency in the formula for mean and std deviation, i.e. to take the mean of the share as well? Or will the mean and std deviation nos. make sense the way I am doing?